# USB IF specification for back powering Hubs

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-hub

Is there any design specification in the USB forum that states what amount of back powering current from a device to a hub is allowed?
I understand that it may be zero but I also can't seem to find such a condition anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: What version of USB?

Comment: USB 2.0, But if there is info available on newer versions, please share them.

Answer (score 1):

Tests for back driving voltage are described in [“USB-IF Full and Low Speed Electrical and Interoperability Compliance Test Procedure"](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB-IFTestProc1_3.pdf) document. The test uses the following fixture:

[image]

Voltages on 15k loads should not exceed 400 mV.

Comment: I think this is helpful, but I am mostly concerned about inrush current coming from a power supply that makes the device use its voltage instead of the hub's voltage. I'm not very sure back voltage can help with identifying that.

Comment: @anxiousPI, this is not just "helpful", but answers your question precisely. Your concern about "inrush current coming from a power supply" makes no sense. Please try to learn exact terminology before asking a technical question.

Comment: Do you know what the analogous test would be for USB 3.0? Should we also do the same tests on the superspeed pins?

Comment: For anyone interested interoception's question was answered here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/603765/how-do-you-do-back-voltage-testing-on-usb-3-0